# Migrate customer domains to different server

Tags: dns, migration

I have a server running an e-commerce platform. Every customer of the platform run on the same of app but on its own domain. I've instructed them to configure DNS like so:

- Create a CNAME "www" pointing to my-domain-name.com
- Change the naked domain pointing to ip-of-mydomain-name

But now, I need to migrate to a new server and the IP will change. I wouldn't like to ask my customers to make the DNS change because it need to be done at the same time (I can't keep both servers (old and new) running at the same time).

I saw Shopify (and other e-commerce platforms) do the same thing I do about DNS, but I have no idea how they handle situations like mine (migrate to different servers).

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to have customers add a CNAME instead of an A record in their domain settings.